# How to convert DocX document to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word, docx

I want to convert or typecaste an existing DocX word doument to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.

```
static DocX g_document;
....
....
function DoSomething()
{
    g_document = DocX.Load(@"C:\Users\RetailWrite.docx");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(g_document); // Here i m getting error
}
```

Then i want to retype caste the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word back to DocX document. How do i do it?

Comment: Google a bit before posting a question - Here is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588995/c-sharp-word-interop-saving-docx-with-word-2003-compatibility-pack

Comment: Na this wont work. I am using DocX.dll library to load the document and then i want to covert the loaded document into Interop.Word.Document

Comment: If you work with `.docx` it's supposed to be a word 2007 on the computer, no? If no, dont use `.docx`. If you generate it automatically, there's a WordML dialect supported by Word 2003. It's not so different than 2007's WordML, but suddenly there are no good tools for generating it, so you'll need to dig into WordML markup.

Comment: Thanks RoadBump. WordML is seriously terrible. So i went for third party dlls instead. Earlier i used OpenXML but now i switched to DocX.dll to manipulate images on the .docx document.

Comment: There's always the dirty way, save Docx document to file and open it with word.

Comment: Not sure but which DLL u have added ? version 11.0 or version 12.0 ? 12.0 should be the proper version.